# Several Files and Forking

Tags: bash

this is my problem. I've heard of forking before, but I haven't really need it until know. I've been trying to get familiar with it, but still I haven't found an explanation to what I want to do.

I have a bash script that iterates in a folder, and sends some orders to a server for each subfolder. The problem is that I have 1000 subfolders, and it will take too much if I do them one after another. So I would like to divide my folders in several process but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Is there a limitation on how you have to send the orders to the server? A maximum parallel limit? An order they need to be done in? What does your current script look like?

Comment: There is no limitation at all. Right now, my script does runs through every single folder at a time and sends a sub to the server.

Comment: Does it wait for each job to finish? Does it need to? If it doesn't wait then I don't see how this can get any faster (and shouldn't be taking all that long I wouldn't think). If it *does* need to wait then I *also* don't see how this can get any faster unless you are allowed to shard jobs in some specific way (hence my original question).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the order for each subfolder in the background and then wait for all of them to complete.

```
for subfolder in $list
do
    process-order $subfolder &
done

wait
```